# Meaning of noun + がどうとかいってたが

Tags: meaning

I found the sentence: 「なんでなんだっけ……　魔王の代替わりがどうとかいってたが……」

Context: the character is reading a newspaper that talks about an event that occurred because of the replacement of the Demon King.

I can understand the main gist of the phrase after seeing it's translation, but I can't understand the meaning of **がどうとかいってたが**, I searched a bit and it seems to be something, could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[どう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86/#jn-154925) means *(some)how* and [とか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B/#jn-157481) makes the statement more vague.

A bit roundabout way to understand is to consider

- 魔王の代替わりが**関係するとか**言っていた said  the replacement of the Demon King was **related** **or something**

and the sentence in question does not even make explicit how the replacement of the Demon King is relevant:

- 魔王の代替わりが**どう**とか言っていた said the replacement of the Demon King was **X** or something

More practically Aがどうとか言っていた can be seen as a set phrase meaning *said something about A* or *said it had something to do with A*. Or as a variant of Aとか何とか言っていた = *said A or something*, *(The speaker vaguely remembers someone) said A*.

Answer (score 2):

どうmeans blah blah blah, or yali yali yeah.
とかmeans "kind of"

So どうとか indicates kind of what someone says.
Also どうとかこうとか、なんとかかんとか and うんたらかんたら have similar meanings.